# Prototype or jQuery for DOM manipulation (client-side dynamic content)

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, prototypejs

I need to know which of these two JavaScript frameworks is better for client-side dynamic content modification for known DOM elements (by id), in terms of performance, memory usage, etc.:

- Prototype's $('id').update(content)
- jQuery's jQuery('#id').html(content)

**EDIT:** My real concerns are clarified at the end of the question.

BTW, both libraries coexist with no conflict in my app, because I'm using RichFaces for JSF development, that's why I can use "jQuery" instead of "$".

I have at least 20 updatable areas in my page, and for each one I prepare content (tables, option lists, etc.), based on some user-defined client-side criteria filtering or some AJAX event, etc., like this:

```
var html = [];
int idx = 0;
...
html[idx++] = '<tr><td class="cell"><span class="link" title="View" onclick="myFunction(';
html[idx++] = param;
html[idx++] = ')"></span>';
html[idx++] = someText;
html[idx++] = '</td></tr>';
...
```

So here comes the question, which is better to use:

```
// Prototype's
$('myId').update(html.join(''));
// or jQuery's
jQuery('#myId').html(html.join(''));
```

Other needed functions are hide() and show(), which are present in both frameworks. Which is better? Also I'm needing to enable/disable form controls, and to read/set their values.

Note that I know my updatable area's id (I don't need CSS selectors at this point). And I must tell that I'm saving these queried objects in some data structure for later use, so they are requested just once when the page is rendered, like this:

```
MyData = {div1:jQuery('#id1'), div2:$('id2'), ...};
...
div1.update('content 1');
div2.html('content 2');
```

So, which is the best practice?

**EDIT:** Clarifying, I'm mostly concerned about:

- Memory usage by these saved objects (it seems to me that jQuery objects add too much overhead), while OTOH my DOM elements are already modified by Prototype's extensions (loaded by default by Richfaces).
- Performance (time) and memory leakage (garbage collection for replaced elements?) when updating the DOM. From the source code, I could see that Prototype replaces the innerHTML and does something with inline scripts. jQuery seems to free memory when calling "empty()" before replacing content.

Please correct me if needed...

Answer (score 1):

You're better off going with jQuery. Both frameworks are great (and I use them both), but in your case jQuery is probably the winner.

In my opinion prototype provides a more natural syntax for javascript development. It does this at the cost of adding methods to some of the core classes, but it's also motivated by ruby where this is the norm.

jQuery on the other hand is far superior at dom manipulation and event observation. Your code will be more concise and manageable in these cases and will benefit from great performance features like event delegation. jQuery also has a much larger community and way more plugins and code samples.

Comment: I agree. I was an early adopter of Prototype and stuck with it for a long time. The syntax of jQuery is much cleaner, the community is larger and there are more goodies. Jquery on a resume helps you get a job. Prototype no longer does.

Answer (score 1):

If you're only interested in the three basic methods "update", "hide" and "show" then jQuery is better suited. It is aimed more at DOM manipulation which is exactly what you need. Then again you could do each of those things in a couple of lines of code, saving the 26KB needed to transfer the jQuery library.

Since your worry is in memory usage look at the jQuery file, it is 77KB uncompressed, how much work do you suppose that is for the browser to execute? Probably much more than that freed by calling `empty()` on a typical DIV.

And you mention Prototype is already in use on the site in which case you shouldn't be *adding* another library. jQuery's abilities are a subset of Prototype's.

This question is nearly a year old so you've probably made your decision by now. For anyone else reading the answer is simple; If something's not broken don't fix it, you already have one capable library installed so use that.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for jQuery. Prototype used to modify default JS objects, which is fine but it means you have to be careful. I believe this is no longer the case though. JQuery also has a large plugin repository and the jquery UI extension for widgets. Btw. With JQuery you can use the familiar dollar sign as well.

Comment: Thanks. As I said, I can use any of them, because both are bundled with RichFaces (I use "$" and "jQuery"), so the decision is not which to install, but which to use for what I need (content modification).